# How to set a default value for a ForeignKey in django that can be changed?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys, default-value

I'm trying to make a project management tool (open source) in django, and while developing, I tried to reproduce this behaviour from Trac that allows the administrator to select a default issue type and a default status so when someone creates a ticket, appears by default unless changed.

How can I reproduce that behaviour in my data model? I saw multiple solutions, but they stablish a fixed default value that can't be changed in time, like using a method for the default value.

I also thought of creating a boolean field in the data model, and when the administrator changes the default value set that objects boolean field to 1 and the rest to 0, but that's a really crappy solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As I'm not sure if this is a per-user setting, per-project setting or a global one - I'll offer two approaches. First (if it is a per-user or per-project setting, attach the defaults to the user/project model). Second, if it is a global setting set it either in the DB (table `defaults` or something) or in a per-app setting module.

Comment: something like https://bitbucket.org/bkroeze/django-livesettings

Comment: It's a per-project setting. I think I'm going to try your approach, attach the default to the project model and then while creating a ticket, make a query that selects for example the statuses of that project and puts by default the one located in the project model. Thanks!

Comment: @TI It's planned to be a multiproject platform, so it's not viable to have that kind of setting around in a file, but thanks anyway! :)